# How can I send ArrayList over Web Service?

Tags: soap, web-services, return-type

Subject is my real question but i wonder that another issue about web services.

What is the key points of web services to return something?

1. Serializable (Because everything
   converts to XML before adding them
   to SOAP Message)
2. ? (What should i do for generic
   class)
3. ?? (How can i put everything (which
   are serializable classes) to one
   return type like Object type)
4. ??? (How can i pass exceptions over
   Web Services?)

[alt text http://docs.sun.com/source/819-3669/images/saaj-noAttach.gif](http://docs.sun.com/source/819-3669/images/saaj-noAttach.gif)
[image]
<sub>(source: [dret.net](https://dret.net/lectures/services-fall06/img/soap-message-attachment.gif))</sub>

[image]

Comment: Did you get some resolution ? Did you try my comments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to return complex type messages to return ArrayList.

To do this, you will have to define this message in your WSDL file.

Check http://fusesource.com/docs/framework/2.2/wsdl/WSDLDefiningArrays.html

Similarly, you will have to return SOAP Fault messages, in case of exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few links with details and examples which will help. (little old ones but good):

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/ws-tip-j2eenet2.html

http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25221_04/web.1013/b25603/apptypemapping.htm